# How should I handle fetching data from the same route using ngrx effects?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

This is simply an architecture question, which I couldn't find the answer to anywhere.

The current scenario is - There is a server that accepts GET requests on one end point. Each request body will have the same structure : requestType (string) and payload (json). The requestType is mapped with a switch case in the backend to essentially just mimic multiple end points.

Now, while creating an Angular/NgRx application that relies on this backend, how should I manage the services? There are about 40 requestTypes, should I make 40 services? Should I create one service that uses httpClient to hit that singular end point and then use a lot of effects to listen to actions and then create the right payload and use the service?

Which approach would be easier to test?

Comment: What does involve the creation of the `right payload` ? Isn't it just the action's props?

Comment: @AndreiGătej not quite. For example if the action requires me to fetch categories, the action simply says "[Home page] Fetch categories" with no props. Otherwise I'd have to add an extra string prop to every action I'll be making.

Comment: I believe that there is a way to create some sort of abstraction. One thing for sure is that I'd move this whole logic in an interceptor. Also knowing that you're sending `{ requestType, payload }`, makes me think of the strategy pattern(or a variation of it), but it depends on how that object is created depending on the action type and how it varies in each case.

Comment: @AndreiGătej ah thanks for mentioning interceptors. This is a concept I didn't know about and I believe I can at least use it for formatting responses from the backend. hough, I'm still not sure how I'd move all of this logic to an interceptor. Could you point me to some article or codebase that uses interceptors for something like this?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not aware of any resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what the backend returns.

If it returns the same kind of data with different flags you can use one store feature with one action and one effect, the action should have `type` property.

If it returns different kind of data, for example Users / Companies etc then, unfortunately, you have to create 40 store features, write actions and effects for them. To reduce the boilerplate process you can try to use `ngrx/data`, I can't call it a very good lib, but in this case it will allow you to specify 40 types and the rest will be done automatically.

Otherwise try to create factory functions and classes.

Comment: Yeah all of the data will be extremely different from each other. But my question is whether I should make multiple services and very light effects, or should I create a singular service that just does a GET request and some error handling, and put most of the logic in 40 different effects?

Comment: I just don't know if writing really complex effects is advised and/or easily tested.

Comment: I personally prefer KISS to keep it as simple as possible and would have a base class if it's possible and then an effect per feature.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll also be making multiple effects as needed, and a single service.